# Printing final (leaf?) nodes in directory listing Python

Tags: python, os.walk

I can walk the directory and print just folder/directory names but I would like to exclude folder names of directories that contain other directories. For some reason I am calling that a "final node" in the tree structure but I could well be fooling myself, wouldn't be the first time. =) On reveiewing the list of other answers perhaps this is called a "leaf node" ?

```
    import os
    chosen_path = (os.getcwd())
    FoldersFound =[] 
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(chosen_path, topdown=True):
        for name in dirs:
            FoldersFound.append(name)
    FoldersFound.sort()
    for FolderName in FoldersFound:
        print FolderName
```

Comment: Do you mind share your code?

Comment: sure, sorry ... let me see if I can work this ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will print the full names of the directories that have no child directories:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(here):
    if not dirs:
        print '%s is a leaf' % root
```

To print only the base name, replace `root` with `os.path.basename(root)`

To put them in a list use:

```
folders = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(here):
    if not dirs:
        folders.append(root)
```

Likewise to put only the basename in the list, replace `root` with `os.path.basename(root)`

Comment: Or the equivalent one-liner (it is Python, after all): `[root for root, dirs, files in os.walk(here) if not dirs]` :)

Comment: thanks gents, I thought I tried to use `if not dirs` but I must have botched the syntax...again no surprise. I'll try again.

Comment: @HannesOvrén Your solution works except that it gives me the full path when I am only wanting to print/collate the final foldername. Possible with your solution?

Comment: Use `os.path.basename(root)` rather than `root`.

Comment: @DanD. thanks, got my result. If I can I'll even see if I can shoehorn that into Hannes' one liner =)

Many thanks to you all.

Comment: Showhorning it really just comes down to `[os.path.basename(root) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(here) if not dirs]` as Dan D sugested.

Comment: Thanks @HannesOvrén 
It seems a couple of directories are _failing to be picked up_ in this.
I've done it multiple times, checked the directories for strange permissions (anything that might make one directory different from another) but I cannot see anything...

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using "os.listdir":

```
import os


def print_leaf_dir(pathname, dirname):
dirnames = [subfolder for subfolder in os.listdir(os.path.join(pathname, dirname)) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(pathname, dirname, subfolder))]

if(dirnames):
    for subfolder in dirnames:
        print_leaf_dir(os.path.join(pathname, dirname), subfolder)
else:
    print(os.path.join(pathname, dirname))


if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    print_leaf_dir(r'C:\TEMP', '')
```