# Random selection of files from one folder and recursively copy them into subfolders

Tags: python, random, copy

I have 500 zip files in a folder called **Data** from which I need to randomly select 5 files and copy those files to the subfolders. I have the folder structure as follows:

```
    Root_Folder  
    |__Data (contains 500 zip files)  
    |__Assign_Folder  
        |__One (subfolder)
            |__a1 (sub-subfolder)
            |__a2 (and so on)
        |__Two (subfolder)
            |__a1 (sub-subfolder)
            |__a2 (and so on)
    |__script.py
```

The Python script is located in the **Root_Folder.** I want to randomly select 5 zip files from the **Data** folder and recursively copy them in each of the **a1, a2, a3, ...** subfolders inside the **One, Two, ...** parent folders. So, in the end I want to have 5 zip files each copied into the **a1, a2, ...** folders inside the **One, Two, ...** parent folders. There are enough subfolders that the files can be easily copied.

I have written the following code:

```
import os
import random
import shutil

data_path = 'Data'
root_folder = 'Assign_Folder'

for folder, subs, files in os.walk(root_folder): 
    # select 5 random files
    filenames = random.sample(os.listdir(data_path), 5)

    for fname in filenames:
        srcpath = os.path.join(data_path, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(srcpath, folder)
```

This code is giving me an error **IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'Assign_Folder'**

Please help me in correcting and completing this task. Thank you.

Comment: You didn't provide the full error trace, so I'm guessing that the
exception was raised by the last line of your
script. `shutil.copyfile` takes as input two file paths.  Here it
seems to may that your second parameter is the directory path in which
you want to copy the file.  This means that you have to append to that
directory path the name of the file.  Something like:
`shutil.copyfile(srcpath, os.path.join(folder, fname))`.

Comment: Also note that `os.walk` traverses all the directories in `Assign_Folder` which means that files will also be copied in directories `Assign_Folder`, `One` and `Two` and as far as I understand it's not what you want.

Comment: The full trace is:  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/Root_Folder/copy_random_files.py", line 22, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile(srcpath, folder)
  File "/home/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'Assign_Folder'

Comment: Yes you are correct. I do not wish to have any files in the Assign_Folder.

Comment: thanks, so yes the problem comes from `copyfile`

Comment: Yes. I have tried your suggestion: shutil.copyfile(srcpath, os.path.join(folder, fname))    It works correctly but it copies files to the Assign_Folder. This is the only problem that remains.

Comment: Look at this [Printing final (leaf?) nodes in directory listing Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146974/printing-final-leaf-nodes-in-directory-listing-python). You'll find a solution for `os.walk` to ignore directories which have sub-directories.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. How do I accept your solution in Stackoverflow? I am new to this platform.

Comment: you're welcome.  I submitted an answer that summarises the comments. You can accept it by clicking on the checkmark left to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shutil.copyfile` fails if the second argument is the directory in
which you want to copy the file.  So you have to append the
destination file name to it.

Also, since you want to copy files only in the leaf directories of
`Assign_Folder`, you have to ignore directories generated by `os.walk`
that do have sub-directories.  You can do that by checking the second
element of tuples generated by `os.walk` (see [Printing final (leaf?)
nodes in directory listing
Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146974/printing-final-leaf-nodes-in-directory-listing-python)).

With these two patches the code becomes:

```py
import os
import random
import shutil

data_path = 'Data'
root_folder = 'Assign_Folder'

for folder, subs, files in os.walk(root_folder):
    if not subs:  #  ignore the directory if it does have sub-directories

        # select 5 random files
        filenames = random.sample(os.listdir(data_path), 5)

        for fname in filenames:
            srcpath = os.path.join(data_path, fname)
            dstpath = os.path.join(folder, fname)
            shutil.copyfile(srcpath, dstpath)
```